# Upgraded Azure, now can't deploy

Tags: azure

I upgraded Azure to a paid account (pay as you go). Now all of a sudden I can't deploy. It says in Visual Studio when I try to deploy:

> Warning: There was no endpoint listening at https://management.core.windows.net/4b7ac332-17a9-4235-96ef-a47c56860bae/services/hostedservices/reckon/certificates that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

I am not using a proxy, nor Team Foundation server.

Comment: Have you [searched for the error](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=azure+There+was+no+endpoint+listening)? That result on MSDN looks relevant.

Comment: I've been through this. None of these are relevant. Not using a proxy, not using Team Foundation server.

Comment: I've added that detail to your question. Not an Azure user myself, but perhaps log a support ticket?

Comment: Did your Subscription ID get changed after an upgrade by chance? If so, you'll need to resetup your deployment settings

Comment: How are you deploying? command line, publish file, package?

Comment: I downloaded a new deployment profile. I use a publish profile in visual studio. Note: things are working again but for no reason at all. One odd thing: I upgraded my Azure package and my subscription is called "Pay-as-you-go" but it still says "3-month trial" in my publish profile. Not sure if that matters. I did download a brand new one.

Answer (score 0):

The uri used for azure management uses a subscription id - if your subscription id changed duringt the upgrade, you'll need to download a new publishsettings file through visual studio